# Do "shew" and "eschew" come from the same root?

Tags: etymology, semantics, affixes

If so, are they antonyms or did one undergo a lexical shift to become the other? Also, is the /es-/ prefix used as a negator in any other English words, or is this case an exception?

Comment: And the question deserved a down-vote?  That's what puts me off posting what seem to be to be sensible questions.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I understand the downvoter's reaction, because this is a question that can be fully answered by reference to primary, easily available, sources.

Answer (score 3):

No, the two words are not related. There is neither a direct relation nor a negation.

"Shew" is an old version of "[show](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=show)" which comes from proto-Germanic "skauwojan", i.e. choose, look at, and other verbs. Even in Proto-Indo-European, there is "skeue", pay attention.

On the other hand, "[eschew](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=eschew)" is from proto-Germanic "skeukhwaz", i.e. escape.